# Get google trackingcode with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

I need to get the tracking code (UA-XXXXX...) in my code after i init google analytics.

```
            (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
                i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
                i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
                }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
                a = s.createElement(o),
                    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
                a.async = 1;
                a.src = g;
                m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
            })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
            ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-XX','auto');
            ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
```

After i init the Google Analytics how to retrieve the UA from the ga object ?

Comment: Sorry, can you explain a bit further? Is the tracking code in the page and you want to get it after the page loads? Or are you saying you want to insert the tracking code after the page loads?

Comment: Sorry - I don't mean to be rude, but could you please explain further what you're trying to achieve? :)

Comment: Its okay. I want to retrieve the UA after i setting it.

Comment: Its because i made a script which people are able to insert into their page. 
My script need to get the UA to perform some actions. 
@Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research i found this method

```
function getUA(){

    var trackers = ga.getAll();
    var code;

    for (var i=0; i < trackers.length; ++i) {
        var tracker = trackers[i];
        code = tracker.get("trackingId");
    }

    return code;
}
```